# get label text of all checked checkbox in user control inside flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, checkbox, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I'm working on a Restaurant POS system, I created a form to show all Extras that users can ask to add to there orders, here is the form :

[image]

Inside this form, I added a `flowlayoutpanel` and I added multiple user controls to this `flowlayoutpanel`, each user control have a `PictureBox` and `Label` and `CheckBox`. I'm filling the user controls in `flowlayoutpanel` like this :

```
flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
            DB_conn.Query2("get_food_extras");
            DB_conn._dr = DB_conn._cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (DB_conn._dr.Read())
            {
                Extra_uc UC = new Extra_uc
                {
                    Extras_ID = DB_conn._dr["ID"].ToString(),
                    Extras_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(DB_conn._dr["price"].ToString()),
                    Extras_name = DB_conn._dr["name"].ToString()
                };
                if (DB_conn._dr["image"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    byte[] image = (byte[])DB_conn._dr["image"];
                    image = Decompress(image);
                    var stream = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                    var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                    UC.Extras_image = bitmap;
                }
                UC.CheckBox1.CheckedChanged += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                UC.MaterialImage.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                UC.Material_name_txt.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                UC.MaterialImage.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                UC.Material_name_txt.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                UC.MaterialImage.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                UC.Material_name_txt.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(UC);
            }

            DB_conn._dr.Close();
```

and I'm able to get label text like this:

```
private void UC_PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Food_Moved)
        {
            string Extra_Name = "";
            CheckState checkd = CheckState.Unchecked;
            if (sender is Label lab)
            {
                Extra_Name = lab.Tag.ToString();
            }
            else if (sender is PictureBox btn1)
            {
                Extra_Name = btn1.Tag.ToString();
            }
            else if (sender is Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2CheckBox ck)
            {
                checkd = ck.CheckState;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(Extra_Name.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            Food_Moved = false;
        }
    }
```

I'm able to get the `label` text for clicked `user control`, What I want now is how to get all `label` texts for checked `checkBox`??

Comment: Instead of directly wiring up the lower level events of your UserControl when you create it, you should make your UserControl raise CUSTOM EVENTS with that information.  The type of the underlying controls in your UserControl shouldn't be apparent to code outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code, you have a `UserControl` named `Extra_uc` that contains the `Extras_name` property which holds the name of an extra item, and a `CheckBox` control which its `Modifiers` property is set to `internal/public`.

If that's the case, you can get the checked items as simple as this:

```cs
private IEnumerable<string> GetCheckedNames() =>
    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType<Extra_uc>()
    .Where(uc => uc.CheckBox1.Checked)
    .Select(uc => uc.Extras_name); // Or maybe uc.Material_name_txt.Text ?
```